# How to write struct's property down to tableViewCell?

Tags: json, swift

I have API url: https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello
that returns structures:

```
struct WordStruct: Codable {
    let word: String
    let phonetic: String
    let phonetics: [Phonetic]
    let meanings: [Meaning]
    let license: License
    let sourceUrls: [String] }

struct License: Codable {
    let name: String
    let url: String }

struct Meaning: Codable {
    let partOfSpeech: String
    let definitions: [Definition] }

struct Definition: Codable {
    let definition: String
    let synonyms: [String]?
    let example: String? }

struct Phonetic: Codable {
    let text: String
    let audio: String
    let sourceURL: String
    let license: License

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case text, audio
        case sourceURL = "sourceUrl"
        case license
    } }
```

And I have correctly decoded JSON to console but I cannot write "definition" property down to tableViewCell (see struct Definition).
And here's my method:

```
var items = [WordStruct]()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

cell.definitionLalel?.text = items[indexPath.row]///the question is here...

return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested but I think the problem will be somewhere here.
I hope you will get the idea. You have to point the meanings array, and then you can get the first element of that array. Something like this:

```
cell.definitionLalel?.text = items[indexPath.row].meanings[0].definitions[0].definition
```